# How do I pick first and last value of ordered group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I pick first and last value of ordered group in postgresql

For eg

```
| col1 | col2                |
|:----:|---------------------|
| A    | 2018-02-21 01:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-21 13:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-21 14:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-21 16:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-22 06:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-22 10:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-23 11:00:01 |
| C    | 2018-02-24 15:00:01 |
```

Output:

```
| col1 | first_value         | last_value          |
|:----:|---------------------|---------------------|
| A    | 2018-02-21 01:00:01 | 2018-02-21 14:00:01 |
| B    | 2018-02-21 16:00:01 | 2018-02-22 06:00:01 |
| A    | 2018-02-22 10:00:01 | 2018-02-23 11:00:01 |
| C    | 2018-02-24 15:00:01 | 2018-02-24 15:00:01 |
```

I tried using lag and lead and got the desired output. But query is becoming very big. Any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use the difference of `row_numbers` to get the first and last value

```
select col1, min(col2) first_value, max(col2) last_value 
from
(
    select *,
            rank() over (order by col1, cast(col2 as date)) sq1,
            dense_rank() over (order by col1, cast(col2 as date)) sq2
    from table t
) a
group by col1, (sq1-sq2)
order by min(col2)
```

Run the derived table query to see what the sequence is generated and how used for grouping.

**Result :**

```
col1 first_value              last_value
A    2018-02-21 01:00:01.000  2018-02-21 14:00:01.000
B    2018-02-21 16:00:01.000  2018-02-22 06:00:01.000
A    2018-02-22 10:00:01.000  2018-02-23 11:00:01.000
C    2018-02-24 15:00:01.000  2018-02-24 15:00:01.000
```

Comment: simple answer I like it. you just forgot to add `order by min(col2) asc` to match OP order.

Comment: you have taken edge case of date, if dates are of same day and within a small time interval, this won't work. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @akashdeep... the above is based on data that u have provided or u could edit the question & limit the specific problem.

Comment: I mean, dates are incremental, which is what I mentioned, and batching of rows will be in ordered manner of dates. Among them, I want first and last value of that batch

Comment: @akashdeep.. still i confused but, let me try on it it you could edit the question to add more data & expected result.